# Swift 3 - Reduce an array to a dictionary with a count of unique elements

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift3

I'm currently migrating a current project to Swift3 (from 2.3) and am having some issues with an extension I have for my Sequence type.
The extension is designed to return a dictionary of unique values from the source array.
i.e. `var myArray = ["Apple","Apple","Orange","Banana","Banana"]`

the ".freq" extension returns a dictionary in the following format.

```
["Apple":2,"Orange":1,"Banana":2]
```

Here is the current Swift 2.3 syntax, which works:

```
extension Sequence where Self.Iterator.Element: Hashable {

    func freq() -> [Self.Iterator.Element: Int] {
        return reduce([:]) { ( accu: [Self.Iterator.Element: Int], element) in
            accu[element] = (accu[element]? + 1) ?? 1
            return accu
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is the the line `accu[element] = (accu[element]? + 1) ?? 1` will not work in Swift 3, due to syntax changes:

> cannot assign through subscript: accu is a let constant

I'm sure its probably an easy fix, but cannot seem to find a relevant example of how to do this in swift3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension Sequence where Self.Iterator.Element: Hashable {

func freq() -> [Self.Iterator.Element: Int] {
    return reduce([:]) {
            ( accu: [Self.Iterator.Element: Int], element) in
            var accu2 = accu
            accu2[element] = (accu2[element] ?? 0) + 1
            return accu2
        }
    }
}
```